# Calculate edges/corners for rectangle/sprite that is rotated

Tags: algorithm, sprite

How I can calculate all corners of rectangle that is rotated and anchorXY is in the middle of it (0.5,0.5).
Can someone provide some function for it please?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to know positions of corners of a rectangle after a rotation? If so, check what *2d linear transformations* are, or edit your question providing some concrete examples, to which we can provide concrete answers.

Comment: Yes corners of rectangle. But when we have anchors of x,y set to middle. So the rotation point is in the middle of the rectangle...

Answer (score 1):

Use trigonometry.

Let initial coordinates of (non-rotated, parallel to axes) rectangle is:
(0,0), (8,10). (bottom left, top right). Let it be rotated by angle `x`, keeping origin constant. Then, new coordinates will be:

(0,0), (8*cos(x), 8*sin(x)), (8*cos(x) - 10*sin(x), 8*sin(x) + 10*cos(x)), (-10*sin(x), 10*cos(x))

You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes.

EDIT:

Translation of axes:

If origin is shifted from (0,0) to (h,k), a point (x,y) will change to (x + h, y + k). So, If anchor of rotation is (0.5, 0.5),

- bring origin to this point (translation of axes)
- Find all points after rotating the axes (see above, rotation of axes)
- Again translate the axes to previous origin (again, translation)

Comment: But when we have anchors of x,y set to middle. So the rotation point is in the middle of the rectangle... how I can than calculate the corners?

Comment: could you provide me a mathematical function for it please?

Comment: @user3673265, see edited answer, if that solves your problem.

Comment: but when anchors are 0.5,0.5 how you can use rotation axes calculation if width & height are different. You would need to calculate it like for a 1/4 of rectangle.

Comment: Think about it. It does not matter. Translate-Rotate-Translate will solve.